# Laravel Yajra Datatables sorting column with 3 set of values

Tags: laravel, datatables, range

I have implemented yajra datatables successfully for all reviews. One review can have 3 statuses: `Approved`, `Pending`, `Blocked`.

I have a column on datatables which is called `Status` and I want to sort column by status. By default the status is being ranged as per `Approved` and `Declined` but not for `Pending`.

Is there any way so I can sort this column by routing on this 3 statuses?

I'm sure that there is some `editColumn` or `filterColumn` method for my question but I'm not finding it any where.

Any way for @andrewjames pleasure I'm adding some non necessary code here:

```
public function indexDataService()
{

    $reviews = DB::table('reviews')
                        ->join('users', 'reviews.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->join('statuses', 'reviews.status_id', '=', 'statuses.id')
                        ->join('products', 'reviews.product_id', 'products.id')
                        ->join('categories', 'reviews.category_id', 'categories.id')
                        ->select([
                            'reviews.*',
                            'reviews.created_at AS created_at', 
                            'statuses.title AS status',
                            DB::raw('CONCAT(users.first_name, "  ", users.last_name) AS full_name'),
                            'products.title',
                            DB::raw('categories.title as category'),
                        ])
                        ->where('reviews.deleted_at', '=', NULL);

    return Datatables::of($reviews)
                        ->addColumn('action', function($review){
                            return view('admin/reviews/reviews_actions', compact('review'));
                        })
                        ->editColumn('created_at', function ($review) {
                            $formatedDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $review->created_at)->format('d-m-Y'); 
                            return $formatedDate;
                        })
                        ->filterColumn('full_name', function ($query, $keyword) {
                            $keywords = trim($keyword);
                            $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, last_name) like ?", ["%{$keywords}%"]);
                        })
                        ->filterColumn('category', function ($query, $keyword) {
                            $keywords = trim($keyword);
                            $query->whereRaw("categories.title like ?", ["%{$keywords}%"]);
                        })
                        ->make(true);
}
```

On blade:

```
<script>

$('#category-reviews-table tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+'" />' );
} );

$(function() {
$('#category-reviews-table').DataTable({
    "sDom":"ltipr",
    processing: false,
    serverSide: true,
    "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Italian.json"
        },
    ajax: '{{ route('admin.reviews.data') }}',
    columnDefs: [
        {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"},
        {   
        targets: [1],
        render: function ( data, type, row ) {
            return type === 'display' && data.length > 10 ?
                data.substr( 0, 20 ) +'…' :
                data;
            }
        }
    ],
    columns: [
        { data: 'full_name', name: 'full_name' },
        { data: 'title', name: 'products.title' },
        { data: 'category', name: 'category'},
        { data: 'no_yes', name: 'reviews.no_yes', searchable:false },
        { data: 'status', name: 'status', searchable:false, 
            render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
                if (data === 'In attessa') {
                  return "<span class=\"badge badge-warning\">In attessa</span>";
                } else if (data === 'Approvata') {
                  return "<span class=\"badge badge-success\">Approvata</span>";
                } else if (data === 'Rifiutata') {
                return "<span class=\"badge badge-danger\">Rifiutata</span>";
                }
            }
        },
        { data: 'created_at', name: 'reviews.created_at', searchable:false  },
        { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable:false }
    ],
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear',        function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    },
});
});
```

Can anyone give me some example how to achieve it?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code which shows what you want to do? I am not sure what you mean by "_range filter this column_". Are you referring to using a `<select>` input where the user can select multiple values (and then filtering on the selected values)?

Comment: No sorry for not being explained well. What I mean by `range` is like ranging a name from a-z or z-a with those little arrows on each column header. I want to range from a to b to c repeatedly.

Comment: oh so you want to implement multiple sort orders on multiple columns ?

Comment: try this example explained by datatables if you're just doing it on DOM. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

Comment: You want to sort your `Status` column by `Approved`, `Declined`, `Pending`, `Approved`, `Declined`, `Pending`, repeatedly...? Is that correct? Then like @MalikWaqas mentioned you have to sort by some other column first. Can you [edit] your question to show us your code, and some sample data?

Comment: Yes that is the point. Bro I know what you want to achieve by asking for code but this is not the case. Any way I will post the code and let see if you can help me. The answer of my question has nothing to do with the already implemented code but anyway...

Comment: @andrewjames happy now?

Comment: @malikWaqas in fact I want only that status column to be sorted one for Approved than for Pending than for Declined repeatedly

Comment: @MarinarioAgalliu since you're displaying status in single column and want  ' approved, declined, pending ' as sorted alphabetically a-z | z-a you can try simple $reviews->orderBy('status', $status_sort_order)->get(); make this order by conditional so when the user click on the header of the coloumn it get's asc or desc

Comment: let me give a try

Comment: For more clearer picture you can send us a screenshot of the table with desired results so we can help you out more.

Comment: I just made it in another way. I added the footer search for that column too but I wanted to achieve that only by sorting the column on header looping through 3 values. Anyway @malikWaqas thank for your try and help.